# How can I configure the iex-ruby-client gem to work with a regular ruby program(not rails)?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am working on a project trying to grab data from the iex finance api and I was wondering how to configure that is a regular ruby program. I've had success in rails but not sure how to do it in a ruby program. I put

## Config file for iex-ruby gem

```
IEX::Api.configure do |config|
  config.publishable_token = 'Tpk_dd88c906f3ae4ac492644c2d0d82281d' # defaults to ENV['IEX_API_PUBLISHABLE_TOKEN']
  config.endpoint = 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/v1' # defaults to 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1'
end
```

in a separate file and require in in a stock.rb file and get the following error:

/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/iex-ruby-client-1.1.0/lib/iex/api.rb:1:in `require_relative': /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/iex-ruby-client-1.1.0/lib/iex/endpoints/chart.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected '.' (SyntaxError)
        options&.each_pair do |k, v|

which looks like a syntax error in the gemfile but im sure i just did something wrong. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Line 14](https://github.com/dblock/iex-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/iex/endpoints/chart.rb#L14) in the `iex-ruby-client-1.1.0/lib/iex/endpoints/chart.rb` looks like this

```
options&.each_pair do |k, v|
```

and the error message tells that Ruby thinks there is a syntax error in that line.

The gem is using safe navigation (`&.`) in that line – a feature that was introduced with Ruby 2.3. That means that gem depends on Ruby 2.3 but does not declare that dependency. On the other hand, you are still running on Ruby 2.2.

Update your Ruby version to at least 2.3 and you should be fine. Or you might want to try downgrading the gem to version `1.0.1` because it looks like the maintainer changed the syntax recently in the latest version.

Actually, I suggest updating your Ruby version to 2.6 or 2.7 because even 2.3 has already reached end-of-life and is not maintained anymore.

Comment: I opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dblock/iex-ruby-client/issues/60) and asked the maintainer to added the missing `required_ruby_version` declaration.